# Asp.Net MVC: Custom AuthorizeAttribute filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult = true on build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roleprovider

I have a custom role provider with a custom AuthorizeAttribute that will redirect to an access denied page if they aren't a member of the particular role. When I build project from visual studio and open page(has AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute in action method)  in browser, `filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult` is always true and it redirects to AccessDenied page. But on next refresh it works fine. Any ideas?

```
public class AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult) //Unauthorized request
            {
              //check if user is not logged in then redirect to login page
              if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
              {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?returnUrl=" +
                filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
              }
              else //user is logged in but don't have required roles to access page
              {
                filterContext.Controller.TempData["NeededRoles"] = base.Roles;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/AccessDenied");
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: @Erik I am using Forms authentication.

Comment: Have you tried override the method `protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)` (from `AuthorizeAttribute`) instead?